# Does SQL performance degrade as the number elements in an "IN" clause increases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-in

I have a query like this,

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Id IN (1,4,3,6,7)
```

There might be millions of customers in the DataBase. Will there be an efficiency problem with   this query ? When the number of Ids inside IN statement are more ? If so, Why and Any workaround ?

I Use SQLServer. Below is my table Structure

```
Id|Name|Designation
```

Id is the primary key -non clustered index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have properly indexed the `Id` column, there should be no problem.  That is the correct method, and if it does not work, you need a new database.  (Millions shouldn't be an issue with most regular pieces of software; if you make it to multiple billions you might need to investigate clustered databases).

Answer (score 3):

This query is as basic as it can get.
If you need to find the name of 5 customers, there is simply no other sane way of writing it.

It will perform well if you have an index on ID.  The performance is almost instantaneous, directly related to the number of items in the IN clause.

If you don't it will scan the table, and the performance becomes directly related to the number of records in the table.

Comment: Yes, Id is a primary key,non clustered index. And even if i have say 10k ids in where clause, Can I assume that it wouldn't result in a performance problem ?

Comment: @Jose: If you list 10k values in the IN clause, you will have performance problems.  The IN clause generally does not scale well.  I've not done the tests recently, but about 20 years ago, the breakpoint was somewhere between about 20 and 100 items in the IN clause.  Above that number, it became more efficient to store the values in a temporary table and join with the temporary table.  YMMV, especially since you didn't identify which DBMS you're using.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 20 years ago is *a long time* in software/hardware .. (I don't even think SQL Server supports 10k, though, but I see no particular reason to think the performance would go south within the limits as long as indexes where employed.)

Comment: @Jonathan :I use SqlServer. My problem is I cannot have a temporary table, I am using linq to entities, and the where condition comes from the local object.So i am left with no option but to use "IN".

Comment: @Jose: it's tempting to say that if you must fight with one hand tied behind your back, you will find it difficult to win.  Maybe that's not entirely fair.  I suggest running some tests; my expectation is that 10k IDs in the statement will cause problems, but I live to be proved wrong.  As already noted, 20 years is a long time; that's a main reason why I qualified my observation with its antiquity.  So, the situation may be different now.  You've been given a heads up that this might cause problems; it's now your call to decide whether you'll do anything about it.

Comment: When you get to very long IN clauses, look at options to utilise table-valued parameters, probably with a stored procedure. Alternative, you can also send it all as a long string and use a dbo.split function or similar to make a table out of the values. SQL Server is really good at hashing two streams together.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I would try, thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute the following query:

```
select * from sys.objects where object_id in (
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,
58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,
85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,
109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,
130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,
151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,381,382,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450,451,452,453,454,455,456,457,458,459,460,461,462,463,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,472,473,474,475,476,477,478,479,480,481,482,483,484,485,486,487,488,489,490,491,492,493,494,495,496,497,498,499,500,501,502,503,504,505,506,507,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,523,524,525,526,527,528,529,530,531,532,533,534,535,536,537,538,539,540,541,542,543,544,545,546,547,548,549,550,551,552,553,554,555,556,557,558,559,560,561,562,563,564,565,566,567,568,569,570,571,572,573,574,575,576,577,578,579,580,581,582,583,584,585,586,587,588,589,590,591,592,593,594,595,596,597,598,599,600,601,602,603,604,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,612,613,614,615,616,617,618,619,620,621,622,623,624,625,626,627,628,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,636,637,638,639,640,641,642,643,644,645,646,647,648,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,656,657,658,659,660,661,662,663,664,665,666,667,668,669,670,671,672,673,674,675,676,677,678,679,680,681,682,683,684,685,686,687,688,689,690,691,692,693,694,695,696,697,698,699,700,701,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710,711,712,713,714,715,716,717,718,719,720,721,722,723,724,725,726,727,728,729,730,731,732,733,734,735,736,737,738,739,740,741,742,743,744,745,746,747,748,749,750,751,752,753,754,755,756,757,758,759,760,761,762,763,764,765,766,767,768,769,770,771,772,773,774,775,776,777,778,779,780,781,782,783,784,785,786,787,788,789,790,791,792,793,794,795,796,797,798,799,800,801,802,803,804,805,806,807,808,809,810,811,812,813,814,815,816,817,818,819,820,821,822,823,824,825,826,827,828,829,830,831,832,833,834,835,836,837,838,839,840,841,842,843,844,845,846,847,848,849,850,851,852,853,854,855,856,857,858,859,860,861,862,863,864,865,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,875,876,877,878,879,880,881,882,883,884,885,886,887,888,889,890,891,892,893,894,895,896,897,898,899,900,901,902,903,904,905,906,907,908,909,910,911,912,913,914,915,916,917,918,919,920,921,922,923,924,925,926,927,928,929,930,931,932,933,934,935,936,937,938,939,940,941,942,943,944,945,946,947,948,949,950,951,952,953,954,955,956,957,958,959,960,961,962,963,964,965,966,967,968,969,970,971,972,973,974,975,976,977,978,979,980,981,982,983,984,985,986,987,988,989,990,991,992,993,994,995,996,997,998,999,1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1012,1013,1014,1015,1016,1017,1018,1019,1020,1021,1022,1023,1024,1025,1026,1027,1028,1029,1030,1031,1032,1033,1034,1035,1036,1037,1038,1039,1040,1041,1042,1043,1044,1045,1046,1047,1048,1049,1050,1051,1052,1053,1054,1055,1056,1057,1058,1059,1060,1061,1062,1063,1064,1065,1066,1067,1068,1069,1070,1071,1072,1073,1074,1075,1076,1077,1078,1079,1080,1081,1082,1083,1084,1085,1086,1087,1088,1089,1090,1091,1092,1093,1094,1095,1096,1097,1098,1099,1100,1101,1102,1103,1104,1105,1106,1107,1108,1109,1110,1111,1112,1113,1114,1115,1116,1117,1118,1119,1120,1121,1122,1123,1124,1125,1126,1127,1128,1129,1130,1131,1132,1133,1134,1135,1136,1137,1138,1139,1140,1141,1142,1143,1144,1145,1146,1147,1148,1149,1150,1151,1152,1153,1154,1155,1156,1157,1158,1159,1160,1161,1162,1163,1164,1165,1166,1167,1168,1169,1170,1171,1172,1173,1174,1175,1176,1177,1178,1179,1180,1181,1182,1183,1184,1185,1186,1187,1188,1189,1190,1191,1192,1193,1194,1195,1196,1197,1198,1199,1200,1201,1202,1203,1204,1205,1206,1207,1208,1209,1210,1211,1212,1213,1214,1215,1216,1217,1218,1219,1220,1221,1222,1223,1224,1225,1226,1227,1228,1229,1230,1231,1232,1233,1234,1235,1236,1237,1238,1239,1240,1241,1242,1243,1244,1245,1246,1247,1248,1249,1250,1251,1252,1253,1254,1255,1256,1257,1258,1259,1260,1261,1262,1263,1264,1265,1266,1267,1268,1269,1270,1271,1272,1273,1274,1275,1276,1277,1278,1279,1280,1281,1282,1283,1284,1285,1286,1287,1288,1289,1290,1291,1292,1293,1294,1295,1296,1297,1298,1299,1300,1301,1302,1303,1304,1305,1306,1307,1308,1309,1310,1311,1312,1313,1314,1315,1316,1317,1318,1319,1320,1321,1322,1323,1324,1325,1326,1327,1328,1329,1330,1331,1332,1333,1334,1335,1336,1337,1338,1339,1340,1341,1342,1343,1344,1345,1346,1347,1348,1349,1350,1351,1352,1353,1354,1355,1356,1357,1358,1359,1360,1361,1362,1363,1364,1365,1366,1367,1368,1369,1370,1371,1372,1373,1374,1375,1376,1377,1378,1379,1380,1381,1382,1383,1384,1385,1386,1387,1388,1389,1390,1391,1392,1393,1394,1395,1396,1397,1398,1399,1400,1401,1402,1403,1404,1405,1406,1407,1408,1409,1410,1411,1412,1413,1414,1415,1416,1417,1418,1419,1420,1421,1422,1423,1424,1425,1426,1427,1428,1429,1430,1431,1432,1433,1434,1435,1436,1437,1438,1439,1440,1441,1442,1443,1444,1445,1446,1447,1448,1449,1450,1451,1452,1453,1454,1455,1456,1457,1458,1459,1460,1461,1462,1463,1464,1465,1466,1467,1468,1469,1470,1471,1472,1473,1474,1475,1476,1477,1478,1479,1480,1481,1482,1483,1484,1485,1486,1487,1488,1489,1490,1491,1492,1493,1494,1495,1496,1497,1498,1499,1500,1501,1502,1503,1504,1505,1506,1507,1508,1509,1510,1511,1512,1513,1514,1515,1516,1517,1518,1519,1520,1521,1522,1523,1524,1525,1526,1527,1528,1529,1530,1531,1532,1533,1534,1535,1536,1537,1538,1539,1540,1541,1542,1543,1544,1545,1546,1547,1548,1549,1550,1551,1552,1553,1554,1555,1556,1557,1558,1559,1560,1561,1562,1563,1564,1565,1566,1567,1568,1569,1570,1571,1572,1573,1574,1575,1576,1577,1578,1579,1580,1581,1582,1583,1584,1585,1586,1587,1588,1589,1590,1591,1592,1593,1594,1595,1596,1597,1598,1599,1600,1601,1602,1603,1604,1605,1606,1607,1608,1609,1610,1611,1612,1613,1614,1615,1616,1617,1618,1619,1620,1621,1622,1623,1624,1625,1626,1627,1628,1629,1630,1631,1632,1633,1634,1635,1636,1637,1638,1639,1640,1641,1642,1643,1644,1645,1646,1647,1648,1649,1650,1651,1652,1653,1654,1655,1656,1657,1658,1659,1660,1661,1662,1663,1664,1665,1666,1667,1668,1669,1670,1671,1672,1673,1674,1675,1676,1677,1678,1679,1680,1681,1682,1683,1684,1685,1686,1687,1688,1689,1690,1691,1692,1693,1694,1695,1696,1697,1698,1699,1700,1701,1702,1703,1704,1705,1706,1707,1708,1709,1710,1711,1712,1713,1714,1715,1716,1717,1718,1719,1720,1721,1722,1723,1724,1725,1726,1727,1728,1729,1730,1731,1732,1733,1734,1735,1736,1737,1738,1739,1740,1741,1742,1743,1744,1745,1746,1747,1748,1749,1750,1751,1752,1753,1754,1755,1756,1757,1758,1759,1760,1761,1762,1763,1764,1765,1766,1767,1768,1769,1770,1771,1772,1773,1774,1775,1776,1777,1778,1779,1780,1781,1782,1783,1784,1785,1786,1787,1788,1789,1790,1791,1792,1793,1794,1795,1796,1797,1798,1799,1800,1801,1802,1803,1804,1805,1806,1807,1808,1809,1810,1811,1812,1813,1814,1815,1816,1817,1818,1819,1820,1821,1822,1823,1824,1825,1826,1827,1828,1829,1830,1831,1832,1833,1834,1835,1836,1837,1838,1839,1840,1841,1842,1843,1844,1845,1846,1847,1848,1849,1850,1851,1852,1853,1854,1855,1856,1857,1858,1859,1860,1861,1862,1863,1864,1865,1866,1867,1868,1869,1870,1871,1872,1873,1874,1875,1876,1877,1878,1879,1880,1881,1882,1883,1884,1885,1886,1887,1888,1889,1890,1891,1892,1893,1894,1895,1896,1897,1898,1899,1900,1901,1902,1903,1904,1905,1906,1907,1908,1909,1910,1911,1912,1913,1914,1915,1916,1917,1918,1919,1920,1921,1922,1923,1924,1925,1926,1927,1928,1929,1930,1931,1932,1933,1934,1935,1936,1937,1938,1939,1940,1941,1942,1943,1944,1945,1946,1947,1948,1949,1950,1951,1952,1953,1954,1955,1956,1957,1958,1959,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027,2028,2029,2030,2031,2032,2033,2034,2035,2036,2037,2038,2039,2040,2041,2042,2043,2044,2045,2046,2047,2048,2049,2050,2051,2052,2053,2054,2055,2056,2057,2058,2059,2060,2061,2062,2063,2064,2065,2066,2067,2068,2069,2070,2071,2072,2073,2074,2075,2076,2077,2078,2079,2080,2081,2082,2083,2084,2085,2086,2087,2088,2089,2090,2091,2092,2093,2094,2095,2096,2097,2098,2099,2100,2101,2102,2103,2104,2105,2106,2107,2108,2109,2110,2111,2112,2113,2114,2115,2116,2117,2118,2119,2120,2121,2122,2123,2124,2125,2126,2127,2128,2129,2130,2131,2132,2133,2134,2135,2136,2137,2138,2139,2140,2141,2142,2143,2144,2145,2146,2147,2148,2149,2150,2151,2152,2153,2154,2155,2156,2157,2158,2159,2160,2161,2162,2163,2164,2165,2166,2167,2168,2169,2170,2171,2172,2173,2174,2175,2176,2177,2178,2179,2180,2181,2182,2183,2184,2185,2186,2187,2188,2189,2190,2191,2192,2193,2194,2195,2196,2197,2198,2199,2200,2201,2202,2203,2204,2205,2206,2207,2208,2209,2210,2211,2212,2213,2214,2215,2216,2217,2218,2219,2220,2221,2222,2223,2224,2225,2226,2227,2228,2229,2230,2231,2232,2233,2234,2235,2236,2237,2238,2239,2240,2241,2242,2243,2244,2245,2246,2247,2248,2249,2250,2251,2252,2253,2254,2255,2256,2257,2258,2259,2260,2261,2262,2263,2264,2265,2266,2267,2268,2269,2270,2271,2272,2273,2274,2275,2276,2277,2278,2279,2280,2281,2282,2283,2284,2285,2286,2287,2288,2289,2290,2291,2292,2293,2294,2295,2296,2297,2298,2299,2300,2301,2302,2303,2304,2305,2306,2307,2308,2309,2310,2311,2312,2313,2314,2315,2316,2317,2318,2319,2320,2321,2322,2323,2324,2325,2326,2327,2328,2329,2330,2331,2332,2333,2334,2335,2336,2337,2338,2339,2340,2341,2342,2343,2344,2345,2346,2347,2348,2349,2350,2351,2352,2353,2354,2355,2356,2357,2358,2359,2360,2361,2362,2363,2364,2365,2366,2367,2368,2369,2370,2371,2372,2373,2374,2375,2376,2377,2378,2379,2380,2381,2382,2383,2384,2385,2386,2387,2388,2389,2390,2391,2392,2393,2394,2395,2396,2397,2398,2399,2400,2401,2402,2403,2404,2405,2406,2407,2408,2409,2410,2411,2412,2413,2414,2415,2416,2417,2418,2419,2420,2421,2422,2423,2424,2425,2426,2427,2428,2429,2430,2431,2432,2433,2434,2435,2436,2437,2438,2439,2440,2441,2442,2443,2444,2445,2446,2447,2448,2449,2450,2451,2452,2453,2454,2455,2456,2457,2458,2459,2460,2461,2462,2463,2464,2465,2466,2467,2468,2469,2470,2471,2472,2473,2474,2475,2476,2477,2478,2479,2480,2481,2482,2483,2484,2485,2486,2487,2488,2489,2490,2491,2492,2493,2494,2495,2496,2497,2498,2499,2500,2501,2502,2503,2504,2505,2506,2507,2508,2509,2510,2511,2512,2513,2514,2515,2516,2517,2518,2519,2520,2521,2522,2523,2524,2525,2526,2527,2528,2529,2530,2531,2532,2533,2534,2535,2536,2537,2538,2539,2540,2541,2542,2543,2544,2545,2546,2547,2548,2549,2550,2551,2552,2553,2554,2555,2556,2557,2558,2559,2560,2561,2562,2563,2564,2565,2566,2567,2568,2569,2570,2571,2572,2573,2574,2575,2576,2577,2578,2579,2580,2581,2582,2583,2584,2585,2586,2587,2588,2589,2590,2591,2592,2593,2594,2595,2596,2597,2598,2599,2600,2601,2602,2603,2604,2605,2606,2607,2608,2609,2610,2611,2612,2613,2614,2615,2616,2617,2618,2619,2620,2621,2622,2623,2624,2625,2626,2627,2628,2629,2630,2631,2632,2633,2634,2635,2636,2637,2638,2639,2640,2641,2642,2643,2644,2645,2646,2647,2648,2649,2650,2651,2652,2653,2654,2655,2656,2657,2658,2659,2660,2661,2662,2663,2664,2665,2666,2667,2668,2669,2670,2671,2672,2673,2674,2675,2676,2677,2678,2679,2680,2681,2682,2683,2684,2685,2686,2687,2688,2689,2690,2691,2692,2693,2694,2695,2696,2697,2698,2699,2700,2701,2702,2703,2704,2705,2706,2707,2708,2709,2710,2711,2712,2713,2714,2715,2716,2717,2718,2719,2720,2721,2722,2723,2724,2725,2726,2727,2728,2729,2730,2731,2732,2733,2734,2735,2736,2737,2738,2739,2740,2741,2742,2743,2744,2745,2746,2747,2748,2749,2750,2751,2752,2753,2754,2755,2756,2757,2758,2759,2760,2761,2762,2763,2764,2765,2766,2767,2768,2769,2770,2771,2772,2773,2774,2775,2776,2777,2778,2779,2780,2781,2782,2783,2784,2785,2786,2787,2788,2789,2790,2791,2792,2793,2794,2795,2796,2797,2798,2799,2800,2801,2802,2803,2804,2805,2806,2807,2808,2809,2810,2811,2812,2813,2814,2815,2816,2817,2818,2819,2820,2821,2822,2823,2824,2825,2826,2827,2828,2829,2830,2831,2832,2833,2834,2835,2836,2837,2838,2839,2840,2841,2842,2843,2844,2845,2846,2847,2848,2849,2850,2851,2852,2853,2854,2855,2856,2857,2858,2859,2860,2861,2862,2863,2864,2865,2866,2867,2868,2869,2870,2871,2872,2873,2874,2875,2876,2877,2878,2879,2880,2881,2882,2883,2884,2885,2886,2887,2888,2889,2890,2891,2892,2893,2894,2895,2896,2897,2898,2899,2900,2901,2902,2903,2904,2905,2906,2907,2908,2909,2910,2911,2912,2913,2914,2915,2916,2917,2918,2919,2920,2921,2922,2923,2924,2925,2926,2927,2928,2929,2930,2931,2932,2933,2934,2935,2936,2937,2938,2939,2940,2941,2942,2943,2944,2945,2946,2947,2948,2949,2950,2951,2952,2953,2954,2955,2956,2957,2958,2959,2960,2961,2962,2963,2964,2965,2966,2967,2968,2969,2970,2971,2972,2973,2974,2975,2976,2977,2978,2979,2980,2981,2982,2983,2984,2985,2986,2987,2988,2989,2990,2991,2992,2993,2994,2995,2996,2997,2998,2999,3000,3001,3002,3003,3004,3005,3006,3007,3008,3009,3010,3011,3012,3013,3014,3015,3016,3017,3018,3019,3020,3021,3022,3023,3024,3025,3026,3027,3028,3029,3030,3031,3032,3033,3034,3035,3036,3037,3038,3039,3040,3041,3042,3043,3044,3045,3046,3047,3048,3049,3050,3051,3052,3053,3054,3055,3056,3057,3058,3059,3060,3061,3062,3063,3064,3065,3066,3067,3068,3069,3070,3071,3072,3073,3074,3075,3076,3077,3078,3079,3080,3081,3082,3083,3084,3085,3086,3087,3088,3089,3090,3091,3092,3093,3094,3095,3096,3097,3098,3099,3100,3101,3102,3103,3104,3105,3106,3107,3108,3109,3110,3111,3112,3113,3114,3115,3116,3117,3118,3119,3120,3121,3122,3123,3124,3125,3126,3127,3128,3129,3130,3131,3132,3133,3134,3135,3136,3137,3138,3139,3140,3141,3142,3143,3144,3145,3146,3147,3148,3149,3150,3151,3152,3153,3154,3155,3156,3157,3158,3159,3160,3161,3162,3163,3164,3165,3166,3167,3168,3169,3170,3171,3172,3173,3174,3175,3176,3177,3178,3179,3180,3181,3182,3183,3184,3185,3186,3187,3188,3189,3190,3191,3192,3193,3194,3195,3196,3197,3198,3199,3200,3201,3202,3203,3204,3205,3206,3207,3208,3209,3210,3211,3212,3213,3214,3215,3216,3217,3218,3219,3220,3221,3222,3223,3224,3225,3226,3227,3228,3229,3230,3231,3232,3233,3234,3235,3236,3237,3238,3239,3240,3241,3242,3243,3244,3245,3246,3247,3248,3249,3250,3251,3252,3253,3254,3255,3256,3257,3258,3259,3260,3261,3262,3263,3264,3265,3266,3267,3268,3269,3270,3271,3272,3273,3274,3275,3276,3277,3278,3279,3280,3281,3282,3283,3284,3285,3286,3287,3288,3289,3290,3291,3292,3293,3294,3295,3296,3297,3298,3299,3300,3301,3302,3303,3304,3305,3306,3307,3308,3309,3310,3311,3312,3313,3314,3315,3316,3317,3318,3319,3320,3321,3322,3323,3324,3325,3326,3327,3328,3329,3330,3331,3332,3333,3334,3335,3336,3337,3338,3339,3340,3341,3342,3343,3344,3345,3346,3347,3348,3349,3350,3351,3352,3353,3354,3355,3356,3357,3358,3359,3360,3361,3362,3363,3364,3365,3366,3367,3368,3369,3370,3371,3372,3373,3374,3375,3376,3377,3378,3379,3380,3381,3382,3383,3384,3385,3386,3387,3388,3389,3390,3391,3392,3393,3394,3395,3396,3397,3398,3399,3400,3401,3402,3403,3404,3405,3406,3407,3408,3409,3410,3411,3412,3413,3414,3415,3416,3417,3418,3419,3420,3421,3422,3423,3424,3425,3426,3427,3428,3429,3430,3431,3432,3433,3434,3435,3436,3437,3438,3439,3440,3441,3442,3443,3444,3445,3446,3447,3448,3449,3450,3451,3452,3453,3454,3455,3456,3457,3458,3459,3460,3461,3462,3463,3464,3465,3466,3467,3468,3469,3470,3471,3472,3473,3474,3475,3476,3477,3478,3479,3480,3481,3482,3483,3484,3485,3486,3487,3488,3489,3490,3491,3492,3493,3494,3495,3496,3497,3498,3499,3500,3501,3502,3503,3504,3505,3506,3507,3508,3509,3510,3511,3512,3513,3514,3515,3516,3517,3518,3519,3520,3521,3522,3523,3524,3525,3526,3527,3528,3529,3530,3531,3532,3533,3534,3535,3536,3537,3538,3539,3540,3541,3542,3543,3544,3545,3546,3547,3548,3549,3550,3551,3552,3553,3554,3555,3556,3557,3558,3559,3560,3561,3562,3563,3564,3565,3566,3567,3568,3569,3570,3571,3572,3573,3574,3575,3576,3577,3578,3579,3580,3581,3582,3583,3584,3585,3586,3587,3588,3589,3590,3591,3592,3593,3594,3595,3596,3597,3598,3599,3600,3601,3602,3603,3604,3605,3606,3607,3608,3609,3610,3611,3612,3613,3614,3615,3616,3617,3618,3619,3620,3621,3622,3623,3624,3625,3626,3627,3628,3629,3630,3631,3632,3633,3634,3635,3636,3637,3638,3639,3640,3641,3642,3643,3644,3645,3646,3647,3648,3649,3650,3651,3652,3653,3654,3655,3656,3657,3658,3659,3660,3661,3662,3663,3664,3665,3666,3667,3668,3669,3670,3671,3672,3673,3674,3675,3676,3677,3678,3679,3680,3681,3682,3683,3684,3685,3686,3687,3688,3689,3690,3691,3692,3693,3694,3695,3696,3697,3698,3699,3700,3701,3702,3703,3704,3705,3706,3707,3708,3709,3710,3711,3712,3713,3714,3715,3716,3717,3718,3719,3720,3721,3722,3723,3724,3725,3726,3727,3728,3729,3730,3731,3732,3733,3734,3735,3736,3737,3738,3739,3740,3741,3742,3743,3744,3745,3746,3747,3748,3749,3750,3751,3752,3753,3754,3755,3756,3757,3758,3759,3760,3761,3762,3763,3764,3765,3766,3767,3768,3769,3770,3771,3772,3773,3774,3775,3776,3777,3778,3779,3780,3781,3782,3783,3784,3785,3786,3787,3788,3789,3790,3791,3792,3793,3794,3795,3796,3797,3798,3799,3800,3801,3802,3803,3804,3805,3806,3807,3808,3809,3810,3811,3812,3813,3814,3815,3816,3817,3818,3819,3820,3821,3822,3823,3824,3825,3826,3827,3828,3829,3830,3831,3832,3833,3834,3835,3836,3837,3838,3839,3840,3841,3842,3843,3844,3845,3846,3847,3848,3849,3850,3851,3852,3853,3854,3855,3856,3857,3858,3859,3860,3861,3862,3863,3864,3865,3866,3867,3868,3869,3870,3871,3872,3873,3874,3875,3876,3877,3878,3879,3880,3881,3882,3883,3884,3885,3886,3887,3888,3889,3890,3891,3892,3893,3894,3895,3896,3897,3898,3899,3900,3901,3902,3903,3904,3905,3906,3907,3908,3909,3910,3911,3912,3913,3914,3915,3916,3917,3918,3919,3920,3921,3922,3923,3924,3925,3926,3927,3928,3929,3930,3931,3932,3933,3934,3935,3936,3937,3938,3939,3940,3941,3942,3943,3944,3945,3946,3947,3948,3949,3950,3951,3952,3953,3954,3955,3956,3957,3958,3959,3960,3961,3962,3963,3964,3965,3966,3967,3968,3969,3970,3971,3972,3973,3974,3975,3976,3977,3978,3979,3980,3981,3982,3983,3984,3985,3986,3987,3988,3989,3990,3991,3992,3993,3994,3995,3996,3997,3998,3999,4000,4001,4002,4003,4004,4005,4006,4007,4008,4009,4010,4011,4012,4013,4014,4015,4016,4017,4018,4019,4020,4021,4022,4023,4024,4025,4026,4027,4028,4029,4030,4031,4032,4033,4034,4035,4036,4037,4038,4039,4040,4041,4042,4043,4044,4045,4046,4047,4048,4049,4050,4051,4052,4053,4054,4055,4056,4057,4058,4059,4060,4061,4062,4063,4064,4065,4066,4067,4068,4069,4070,4071,4072,4073,4074,4075,4076,4077,4078,4079,4080,4081,4082,4083,4084,4085,4086,4087,4088,4089,4090,4091,4092,4093,4094,4095,4096,4097,4098,4099,4100,4101,4102,4103,4104,4105,4106,4107,4108,4109,4110,4111,4112,4113,4114,4115,4116,4117,4118,4119,4120,4121,4122,4123,4124,4125,4126,4127,4128,4129,4130,4131,4132,4133,4134,4135,4136,4137,4138,4139,4140,4141,4142,4143,4144,4145,4146,4147,4148,4149,4150,4151,4152,4153,4154,4155,4156,4157,4158,4159,4160,4161,4162,4163,4164,4165,4166,4167,4168,4169,4170,4171,4172,4173,4174,4175,4176,4177,4178,4179,4180,4181,4182,4183,4184,4185,4186,4187,4188,4189,4190,4191,4192,4193,4194,4195,4196,4197,4198,4199,4200,4201,4202,4203,4204,4205,4206,4207,4208,4209,4210,4211,4212,4213,4214,4215,4216,4217,4218,4219,4220,4221,4222,4223,4224,4225,4226,4227,4228,4229,4230,4231,4232,4233,4234,4235,4236,4237,4238,4239,4240,4241,4242,4243,4244,4245,4246,4247,4248,4249,4250,4251,4252,4253,4254,4255,4256,4257,4258,4259,4260,4261,4262,4263,4264,4265,4266,4267,4268,4269,4270,4271,4272,4273,4274,4275,4276,4277,4278,4279,4280,4281,4282,4283,4284,4285,4286,4287,4288,4289,4290,4291,4292,4293,4294,4295,4296,4297,4298,4299,4300,4301,4302,4303,4304,4305,4306,4307,4308,4309,4310,4311,4312,4313,4314,4315,4316,4317,4318,4319,4320,4321,4322,4323,4324,4325,4326,4327,4328,4329,4330,4331,4332,4333,4334,4335,4336,4337,4338,4339,4340,4341,4342,4343,4344,4345,4346,4347,4348,4349,4350,4351,4352,4353,4354,4355,4356,4357,4358,4359,4360,4361,4362,4363,4364,4365,4366,4367,4368,4369,4370,4371,4372,4373,4374,4375,4376,4377,4378,4379,4380,4381,4382,4383,4384,4385,4386,4387,4388,4389,4390,4391,4392,4393,4394,4395,4396,4397,4398,4399,4400,4401,4402,4403,4404,4405,4406,4407,4408,4409,4410,4411,4412,4413,4414,4415,4416,4417,4418,4419,4420,4421,4422,4423,4424,4425,4426,4427,4428,4429,4430,4431,4432,4433,4434,4435,4436,4437,4438,4439,4440,4441,4442,4443,4444,4445,4446,4447,4448,4449,4450,4451,4452,4453,4454,4455,4456,4457,4458,4459,4460,4461,4462,4463,4464,4465,4466,4467,4468,4469,4470,4471,4472,4473,4474,4475,4476,4477,4478,4479,4480,4481,4482,4483,4484,4485,4486,4487,4488,4489,4490,4491,4492,4493,4494,4495,4496,4497,4498,4499,4500,4501,4502,4503,4504,4505,4506,4507,4508,4509,4510,4511,4512,4513,4514,4515,4516,4517,4518,4519,4520,4521,4522,4523,4524,4525,4526,4527,4528,4529,4530,4531,4532,4533,4534,4535,4536,4537,4538,4539,4540,4541,4542,4543,4544,4545,4546,4547,4548,4549,4550,4551,4552,4553,4554,4555,4556,4557,4558,4559,4560,4561,4562,4563,4564,4565,4566,4567,4568,4569,4570,4571,4572,4573,4574,4575,4576,4577,4578,4579,4580,4581,4582,4583,4584,4585,4586,4587,4588,4589,4590,4591,4592,4593,4594,4595,4596,4597,4598,4599,4600,4601,4602,4603,4604,4605,4606,4607,4608,4609,4610,4611,4612,4613,4614,4615,4616,4617,4618,4619,4620,4621,4622,4623,4624,4625,4626,4627,4628,4629,4630,4631,4632,4633,4634,4635,4636,4637,4638,4639,4640,4641,4642,4643,4644,4645,4646,4647,4648,4649,4650,4651,4652,4653,4654,4655,4656,4657,4658,4659,4660,4661,4662,4663,4664,4665,4666,4667,4668,4669,4670,4671,4672,4673,4674,4675,4676,4677,4678,4679,4680,4681,4682,4683,4684,4685,4686,4687,4688,4689,4690,4691,4692,4693,4694,4695,4696,4697,4698,4699,4700,4701,4702,4703,4704,4705,4706,4707,4708,4709,4710,4711,4712,4713,4714,4715,4716,4717,4718,4719,4720,4721,4722,4723,4724,4725,4726,4727,4728,4729,4730,4731,4732,4733,4734,4735,4736,4737,4738,4739,4740,4741,4742,4743,4744,4745,4746,4747,4748,4749,4750,4751,4752,4753,4754,4755,4756,4757,4758,4759,4760,4761,4762,4763,4764,4765,4766,4767,4768,4769,4770,4771,4772,4773,4774,4775,4776,4777,4778,4779,4780,4781,4782,4783,4784,4785,4786,4787,4788,4789,4790,4791,4792,4793,4794,4795,4796,4797,4798,4799,4800,4801,4802,4803,4804,4805,4806,4807,4808,4809,4810,4811,4812,4813,4814,4815,4816,4817,4818,4819,4820,4821,4822,4823,4824,4825,4826,4827,4828,4829,4830,4831,4832,4833,4834,4835,4836,4837,4838,4839,4840,4841,4842,4843,4844,4845,4846,4847,4848,4849,4850,4851,4852,4853,4854,4855,4856,4857,4858,4859,4860,4861,4862,4863,4864,4865,4866,4867,4868,4869,4870,4871,4872,4873,4874,4875,4876,4877,4878,4879,4880,4881,4882,4883,4884,4885,4886,4887,4888,4889,4890,4891,4892,4893,4894,4895,4896,4897,4898,4899,4900,4901,4902,4903,4904,4905,4906,4907,4908,4909,4910,4911,4912,4913,4914,4915,4916,4917,4918,4919,4920,4921,4922,4923,4924,4925,4926,4927,4928,4929,4930,4931,4932,4933,4934,4935,4936,4937,4938,4939,4940,4941,4942,4943,4944,4945,4946,4947,4948,4949,4950,4951,4952,4953,4954,4955,4956,4957,4958,4959,4960,4961,4962,4963,4964,4965,4966,4967,4968,4969,4970,4971,4972,4973,4974,4975,4976,4977,4978,4979,4980,4981,4982,4983,4984,4985,4986,4987,4988,4989,4990,4991,4992,4993,4994,4995,4996,4997,4998,4999,5000,5001,5002,5003,5004,5005,5006,5007,5008,5009,5010,5011,5012,5013,5014,5015,5016,5017,5018,5019,5020,5021,5022,5023,5024,5025,5026,5027,5028,5029,5030,5031,5032,5033,5034,5035,5036,5037,5038,5039,5040,5041,5042,5043,5044,5045,5046,5047,5048,5049,5050,5051,5052,5053,5054,5055,5056,5057,5058,5059,5060,5061,5062,5063,5064,5065,5066,5067,5068,5069,5070,5071,5072,5073,5074,5075,5076,5077,5078,5079,5080,5081,5082,5083,5084,5085,5086,5087,5088,5089,5090,5091,5092,5093,5094,5095,5096,5097,5098,5099,5100,5101,5102,5103,5104,5105,5106,5107,5108,5109,5110,5111,5112,5113,5114,5115,5116,5117,5118,5119,5120,5121,5122,5123,5124,5125,5126,5127,5128,5129,5130,5131,5132,5133,5134,5135,5136,5137,5138,5139,5140,5141,5142,5143,5144,5145,5146,5147,5148,5149,5150,5151,5152,5153,5154,5155,5156,5157,5158,5159,5160,5161,5162,5163,5164,5165,5166,5167,5168,5169,5170,5171,5172,5173,5174,5175,5176,5177,5178,5179,5180,5181,5182,5183,5184,5185,5186,5187,5188,5189,5190,5191,5192,5193,5194,5195,5196,5197,5198,5199,5200,5201,5202,5203,5204,5205,5206,5207,5208,5209,5210,5211,5212,5213,5214,5215,5216,5217,5218,5219,5220,5221,5222,5223,5224,5225,5226,5227,5228,5229,5230,5231,5232,5233,5234,5235,5236,5237,5238,5239,5240,5241,5242,5243,5244,5245,5246,5247,5248,5249,5250,5251,5252,5253,5254,5255,5256,5257,5258,5259,5260,5261,5262,5263,5264,5265,5266,5267,5268,5269,5270,5271,5272,5273,5274,5275,5276,5277,5278,5279,5280,5281,5282,5283,5284,5285,5286,5287,5288,5289,5290,5291,5292,5293,5294,5295,5296,5297,5298,5299,5300,5301,5302,5303,5304,5305,5306,5307,5308,5309,5310,5311,5312,5313,5314,5315,5316,5317,5318,5319,5320,5321,5322,5323,5324,5325,5326,5327,5328,5329,5330,5331,5332,5333,5334,5335,5336,5337,5338,5339,5340,5341,5342,5343,5344,5345,5346,5347,5348,5349,5350,5351,5352,5353,5354,5355,5356,5357,5358,5359,5360,5361,5362,5363,5364,5365,5366,5367,5368,5369,5370,5371,5372,5373,5374,5375,5376,5377,5378,5379,5380,5381,5382,5383,5384,5385,5386,5387,5388,5389,5390,5391,5392,5393,5394,5395,5396,5397,5398,5399,5400,5401,5402,5403,5404,5405,5406,5407,5408,5409,5410,5411,5412,5413,5414,5415,5416,5417,5418,5419,5420,5421,5422,5423,5424,5425,5426,5427,5428,5429,5430,5431,5432,5433,5434,5435,5436,5437,5438,5439,5440,5441,5442,5443,5444,5445,5446,5447,5448,5449,5450,5451,5452,5453,5454,5455,5456,5457,5458,5459,5460,5461,5462,5463,5464,5465,5466,5467,5468,5469,5470,5471,5472,5473,5474,5475,5476,5477,5478,5479,5480,5481,5482,5483,5484,5485,5486,5487,5488,5489,5490,5491,5492,5493,5494,5495,5496,5497,5498,5499,5500,5501,5502,5503,5504,5505,5506,5507,5508,5509,5510,5511,5512,5513,5514,5515,5516,5517,5518,5519,5520,5521,5522,5523,5524,5525,5526,5527,5528,5529,5530,5531,5532,5533,5534,5535,5536,5537,5538,5539,5540,5541,5542,5543,5544,5545,5546,5547,5548,5549,5550,5551,5552,5553,5554,5555,5556,5557,5558,5559,5560,5561,5562,5563,5564,5565,5566,5567,5568,5569,5570,5571,5572,5573,5574,5575,5576,5577,5578,5579,5580,5581,5582,5583,5584,5585,5586,5587,5588,5589,5590,5591,5592,5593,5594,5595,5596,5597,5598,5599,5600,5601,5602,5603,5604,5605,5606,5607,5608,5609,5610,5611,5612,5613,5614,5615,5616,5617,5618,5619,5620,5621,5622,5623,5624,5625,5626,5627,5628,5629,5630,5631,5632,5633,5634,5635,5636,5637,5638,5639,5640,5641,5642,5643,5644,5645,5646,5647,5648,5649,5650,5651,5652,5653,5654,5655,5656,5657,5658,5659,5660,5661,5662,5663,5664,5665,5666,5667,5668,5669,5670,5671,5672,5673,5674,5675,5676,5677,5678,5679,5680,5681,5682,5683,5684,5685,5686,5687,5688,5689,5690,5691,5692,5693,5694,5695,5696,5697,5698,5699,5700,5701,5702,5703,5704,5705,5706,5707,5708,5709,5710,5711,5712,5713,5714,5715,5716,5717,5718,5719,5720,5721,5722,5723,5724,5725,5726,5727,5728,5729,5730,5731,5732,5733,5734,5735,5736,5737,5738,5739,5740,5741,5742,5743,5744,5745,5746,5747,5748,5749,5750,5751,5752,5753,5754,5755,5756,5757,5758,5759,5760,
5761,5762,5763,5764,5765,5766,5767,5768,5769,5770,5771,5772,5773,5774,5775,5776)
```

(I'm not going to break up all the lines).

In the resulting query, approximately 5% of the cost of the query is taken up with a constant scan (which is effectively turning all of those numbers into a temp table internally and that table is then passed to a join operator).

But, this is a remarkably *simple* query overall. For any more complex query, I'd expect that the cost, as a percentage, will go down (since I expect the absolute cost to remain the same)

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the question that was asked, but, say your list of IDs came from another query:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE Id IN (SELECT ID FROM X WHERE X.FIELD = COND)
```

Then this is cause to rewrite your query using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT Name
FROM   CUSTOMERS
WHERE  EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM   X
    WHERE  X.FIELD = COND
    AND    X.ID = CUSTOMERS.ID
);
```

This is efficient because `EXISTS` gives more opportunity for the optimizer to determine an efficient execution path, whereas `IN` forces the subquery to be fully evaluated.

The query you specified didn't have a subsquery. It just has a list of constants which has little opportunity to be further optimized. As is, you have to do with the best you got, i.e. index the `ID` column as recommended by @zebediah49.